# Javascript fetch api posted file to C# controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core, fetch-api

I am trying to use newer Fetch api to Post File collection to backend C# .

```
let postFilesTask = fetch('/Home/Upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                body: formData     
              })
```

formData is formed as following in typescript:

```
var acp_file  = (document.querySelector("[name=acp]") as HTMLInputElement).files;
        var ava_file  = (document.querySelector("[name=acp]") as HTMLInputElement).files;

        var formData = new FormData();

        if((acp_file as FileList).length > 0 ){        
         formData.append("acp_file" ,(acp_file as FileList)[0] );
        }
        if((ava_file as FileList).length > 0 ){          
            formData.append("ava_file" ,(ava_file as FileList)[0] );
           }
```

My issue is on C# controller . Iam unable to get hold of the File.  With older XMLHttpRequest object I see `Request.Form.Files` gets populated .   However with Fetch api I cant get hold of the files . Although `HttpContext.Request.Body` seems to have the Stream with files content in it.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated .

Comment: Try this and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016213/attempting-to-upload-image-with-fetch-api-and-c-sharp-web-api

Comment: @frostshoxx thanks for the link.. will try it out